# can an app size be estimated before it is actually implemented?

Tags: android

I come up with a question while I am developing an android app.
I would like to know if there is a tool to estimate an app size before I really start implementing it. for example, the codes in network layer have been implemented with `OkHttp` networking library and the app size is currently 5MB. however, I would like to anticipate the app size if I replace codes in network layer with `Retrofit2` networking library before I really implement codes with `Retrofit2` networking library. So I would like to know if it would make the app size less than 5MB or more than 5MB once `OkHttp` is replaced with `Retrofit2`

in this case, are there any ways to estimate the app size with the new implementation?

Comment: in worst case scenario it will take your app size + size of retrofit2.aar

Comment: how does Proguard/Dexguard/R8 factor into this, since they can shrink your APK size?